# SSLHandshakeException : jetty server does not pick any of cipher to initiate SSL handshake

Tags: ssl, encryption, jetty, cxf, handshake

client is sending a list of cipher while sending request but cxf-jetty server 
  does not accept any of the given cipher and closed the session. 
   below is SSL logs from server side. it work when server runs with jdk6 but not with higher version of java.  I tried setting https.protocol but nothing helped. i verified all keystore are updated in cacerts as well. any clue or help would be appreciated ?? 
  also server is created using org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean

```
            tp1402834900-33, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 227
            *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
            RandomCookie:  GMT: 1496138621 bytes = { 96, 63, 100, 252, 232, 36, 198, 68, 124, 190, 117, 1, 205, 237, 23, 156, 66, 68, 27, 72, 46, 44, 245, 6, 67, 240, 24, 181 }
            Session ID:  {}
            Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5]
            Compression Methods:  { 0 }
            Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
            Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
            Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x4, signature:0x2), SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
            ***
            [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 227
                                          ...
            %% Initialized:  [Session-12, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
            qtp1402834900-29, called closeOutbound()
            qtp1402834900-29, closeOutboundInternal()
```

and logs from client side shows SSLHandshake exception

```
   Thread-38, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 227
   Thread-38, received EOFException: error
   Thread-38, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote 
   host closed connection during handshake
   Thread-38, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
   Thread-38, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
   Thread-38, called closeSocket
   Thread-38, called close
   Thread-38, called closeInternal
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 is very old, and considered End-Of-Life with Oracle.

When you upgrade Java versions you are also rapidly upgrading what it means to have a secure and encrypted connection on the public internet.

Eg:

- SSLv3 was deprecated and disabled.
- Hundreds of ciphers were deprecated and disabled.
- TLS/1.1 and TLS/1.2 were introduced

For you to have success you *MUST* have a *client* that talks TLS/1.2 with modern cipher suites, and no deprecated or disabled cipher suites or protocols.

This means no SHA1, no MD5, no small RSA keysize, no SSLv3, no RC4, etc ...

For the complete list see the JVM disabled list ...

```sh
$ grep -E "^j.*disabled" $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, \
```

For Jetty 9.3+ you can enable the server start dump, and look at the `SslContextFactory` details, which will reveal what protocols and ciphers are actually enabled.

```sh
$ cd /path/to/mybase && \
 java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist.jar -Djetty.dump.start=true
```

```
SslContextFactory@1ed4004b(null,null) trustAll=false
 +- Protocol Selections
 |   +- Enabled (size=3)
 |   |   +- TLSv1
 |   |   +- TLSv1.1
 |   |   +- TLSv1.2
 |   +- Disabled (size=2)
 |       +- SSLv2Hello - ConfigExcluded:'SSLv2Hello'
 |       +- SSLv3 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'SSLv3'
 +- Cipher Suite Selections
     +- Enabled (size=15)
     |   +- TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
     |   +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     |   +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     +- Disabled (size=42)
         +- SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - JreDisabled:java.security
         +- TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - JreDisabled:java.security
         +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5 - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - JreDisabled:java.security, ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ConfigExcluded:'^.*_(MD5|SHA|SHA1)$'
         +- TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256 - JreDisabled:java.security
```

For long term success, you MUST keep your java JVM up to date and honor the JVM expiration dates for each release, as the security layers on the JVM do update rapidly (in terms of bugs, implementation, and configuration).  This is a non-optional requirement if you plan on using encryption on the public internet or plan on supporting modern web browsers (which also follow the deprecations of protocols and cipher suites)